# Scattering cross-section in Curved space-time

Tags: general-relativity, scattering, scattering-cross-section, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Consider the following two definitions for differential cross-section $\sigma(\theta,\phi)$ that one often encounters in classical mechanics and in non-relativistic quantum mechanics:

- $\textbf{Definition 1}:$ Cross-section for scattering in a given direction $d\Omega$  (see section 3.10 in Goldstein's $\textit{Classical Mechanics}$) is defined as:
  $$\sigma(\theta,\phi)d\Omega=\frac{no.\;of\;particles\;scattered\;into\;solid\;angle\;d\Omega\;per\;unit\;time}{incident\;intensity}$$
- $\textbf{Definition 2}:$ In Partial Wave method (see Cohen-Tannoudji, $\textit{Quantum mechanics, vol.-2}$), the differential cross-section is defined as square of the modulus of scattering amplitude:
  $$f(\theta)=\frac{1}{2i\omega}\sum_{l=0}(2l+1)[e^{2i\delta_l}-1]P_l(\cos\theta)$$ $$\sigma(\theta,\phi)=|f(\theta,\phi)|^2$$

We know that for non-relativistic dynamics, these two definitions for cross-sections are equivalent (see [How to prove the equivalence of two definitions of the scattering cross section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91497/)). However, is this equivalence also true in a curved space-time manifold? How does existence of shear, vorticity/ relative twist and divergence in an incident beam impacts differential cross-section $\sigma(\theta,\phi)$? In other words, how does the presence of intrinsic curvature (Riemann tensor) modify the above definitions for scattering cross-section?

Comment: For asymptotically flat spacetimes all quantities used to define cross-sections and amplitudes are taken at (various) infinities, so their definitions (and corresponding equivalences) are the same as in flat case. For backgrounds with other asymptotics (such as cosmological spacetimes), first one needs to define asymptotic (in/out) states compatible with such backgrounds.

Comment: @A.V.S. Thanks for the comment!! Can you suggest any reference(s) where calculations for scattering cross section has been done, say for asymptotically flat space-time? I was wondering if the incident beam at past infinity had any of these shear, vorticity, divergences, how would that affect the differential cross section. If the beam travels through a gravitational potential well for a long time, then the effects of these contributions will grow and it might be significant to the overall cross section.

Comment: Incident beams corresponding to momentum eigenstates cannot have shear/vorticity at infinity.

Comment: Let's say we start with momentum eigenstates defined on past  infinity. As this beam travels through curved space time, it will gain shear, vorticity, divergences following Raychaudhuri's equations...so by the time it reaches future infinity , it won't be momentum eigenstates anymore. I find this very similar (and of course, it has to be)to idea of how vacuum state of a quantum field in future & past infinity of a curved space-time won't agree with each other.

Comment: If the spacetime is asymptotically flat that all vorticity/shear of the beam would be decaying in the wave zone. My point is that this is no different than flat space and e.g. magnetic field, which can make charged particles go on corkscrew trajectories. So if magnetic field decays fast enough at infinity, all vorticity in the beam would also decay. OTOH if there is something like a solenoid stretching to infinity, then vorticity in the beam could also remain. But for such situations, maybe differential cross-section with an angle parameter is not the way to handle this.